# TYPO3 news - defining own template

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news, typo3-extensions

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.14 with the news extension. I want to switch between different views in the backend.

Page TS in root:

```
tx_news.templateLayouts {     
 Custom = Gesamter Artikel2
}
```

[image]

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:n="http://typo3.org/ns/GeorgRinger/News/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="General" />
<!--
    =====================
        Templates/News/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
    <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
    <f:if condition="{news}">
        <f:then>
            <div class="news-list-view">
                <f:if condition="{settings.hidePagination}">
                    <f:then>
                        <f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem">
                            <f:if condition="{0:settings.templateLayout} == {0:'Custom}">
                                <f:then>
                                    <f:render partial="List/GesamteArtikel" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings, className:className, view:'list'}"/>
                                </f:then>
                                <f:else>
                                    <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings, className:className, view:'list'}"/>
                                </f:else>
                            </f:if>
                        </f:for> 
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>
                        <n:widget.paginate objects="{news}" as="paginatedNews" configuration="{settings.list.paginate}" initial="{offset:settings.offset,limit:settings.limit}">
                            <f:for each="{paginatedNews}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
                                <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings,iterator:iterator}" />
                            </f:for>
                        </n:widget.paginate>
                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
            </div>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <div class="no-news-found">
                <f:translate key="list_nonewsfound" />
            </div>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
    <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
</f:section>
</html>
```

In the same folder where I have my List.html I've added my own file named GesamteArtikel.html

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

(Changed location of file)

I figured out that it has no impact. I changed it to something like:

```
            <f:then>
                <f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem">
                    <f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 'Custom'">
                        <f:then>
                            <f:render partial="GesamteArtikel" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings, className:className, view:'list'}"/>
                        </f:then>
                        <f:else>
                            <f:render partial="GesamteArtikel" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings, className:className, view:'list'}"/>
                        </f:else>
                    </f:if>
                </f:for> 
            </f:then>
```

And it did nothing.

It uses

```
            <f:else>
                <n:widget.paginate objects="{news}" as="paginatedNews" configuration="{settings.list.paginate}" initial="{offset:settings.offset,limit:settings.limit}">
                    <f:for each="{paginatedNews}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
                        <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings,iterator:iterator}" />
                    </f:for>
                </n:widget.paginate>
            </f:else>
```

I then changed it to

```
            <f:else>
                <n:widget.paginate objects="{news}" as="paginatedNews" configuration="{settings.list.paginate}" initial="{offset:settings.offset,limit:settings.limit}">
                    <f:for each="{paginatedNews}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
                        <f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 'Layout'">
                            <f:then>
                                <f:render partial="GesamteArtikel" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings, className:className, view:'list'}"/>
                            </f:then>
                            <f:else>
                                <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings, className:className, view:'list'}"/>
                            </f:else>
                        </f:if>
                    </f:for>
                </n:widget.paginate>
            </f:else>
```

But it then uses the Item.html only
If I tell both if statements to use GesamteArtikel (custom template) it will use it, but I don't want to override the old item.html. I want to use my custom layout when I select it in the backend...

Comment: You might also want to check [this documentation topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typo3/2196/fluid-templating-in-typo3#t=201703140544357726448).

Answer (score 0):

Two things might help:

Firstly it looks like you‘re missing a single quote in your comparison:

> `<f:if condition="{0:settings.templateLayout} == {0:'Custom}">`

and you can do string comparisons without array bypass, so what you get is:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 'Custom'">
```

The second thing is the location of the file for your custom layout:

> In the same folder where I have my List.html I've added my own file named GesamteArtikel.html

You need to put it somewhere in your partial root paths, like `EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Partials/List/` sibling of the partial `List/Item` (in case you override that one).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help... I changed my f:if condition like so: 
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 'Layout'">
And put the files into different locations. 
Here's my old list.html 
news/Resources/Private/Partials/List
Here's my custom template
news/Resources/Private/Partials

But I figured something out, there still might be a problem with the f:if condition. Check out my updated answer

Comment: (changed Custom to Layout just for test purpose)